# Java run time error - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError wrong name

Tags: java, exception

When I try to run my code from the command line, I get the following exception error;

```
    X:\User temp\httpclient>java httpclient_main 10 10
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: httpclient_main (wron
g name: httpclient/httpclient_main)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

httpclient_main.java;

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package httpclient;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author tsothcott
 */
public class httpclient_main {
    protected String host;
    protected String file;
    protected int port;
    protected DataInputStream in;
    protected DataOutputStream out;
    static double threadResult;

    String get_file()
    {
        return this.file;
    }
    DataOutputStream get_outputstream() {
        return this.out;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputTxt servers = new InputTxt();
        threadResult = 0.0D;

        SharedCell cell = new SharedCell();
        if(args.length <1)
            throw new IOException("Usage: HTTPClient URL Number_Thread");

        int num_thread = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int count_interval = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        servers.printservers();

        Manufacture prod = new Manufacture(cell, num_thread, count_interval);
        prod.start();


    }


}
```

Screenshot of project structure;
[image: Project Structure]

Howewver, when I run it from inside NetBeans, it runs fine?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Post your code, and make sure you have enought libs.

Comment: In what package is hour main class?

Comment: read it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: Why did not you search the web (or stackoverflow) before asking a question for millionth time?

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError comes when class file of your code is present at compile time but not found at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

According to your posted command line output, you are invoking the program from *inside* the package `httpclient`. Your current dir is

```
X:\User temp\Tom Sothcott\httpclient
```

That is wrong. You must invoke your Java programs from the project's root directory. In this case, that will be

```
X:\User temp\Tom Sothcott
```

And of course, you must provide the fully qualified class name, as Ihsan Kocak told you.

Answer (score 0):

```
java httpclient_main 10 10
```

It is wrong usage.Use this parameter with package name.eg.`java httpclient.httpclient_main 10 10`

Comment: Now it won't even run;

`Error: Could not find or load main class httpclient.httpclient_main`

Comment: You can try these two when you are getting the error: 'could not find or load main class'

If your class file is saved in following directory with HelloWorld program name d:\sample

1.java -cp d:\sample HelloWorld
2.java -cp . HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

1. Have `.` in your classpath and execute the java command at `X:\User temp\Tom Sothcott`, OR, have `X:\User temp\Tom Sothcott` directly in your classpath
2. Execute by `java httpclient.httpclient_main 10 10`

`java` command is expecting the **fully qualified classname** for the class containing the main method to execute.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   httpclient_main

So, you ran it as `java httpclient_main`. It's expecting a `httpclient_main.clas`s without any package.

The class is trying to tell you that it has a `package httpclient;`. You need to run it from the package root on. Go one folder up so that your class folder contains the `httpclient` folder representing the package and then execute

```
java httpclient/httpclient_main.
```